# AEM CQ allowedParents and allowedChildren properties in templates

Tags: xml, aem

I need to create the following model pages(in localhost:4502/siteadmin):

```
Basepage
    |
    Homepage
        |
        Contentpage1
             |
             Contentpage2
```

Basepage - main page, can create only the homepage

basepage template .context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
jcr:title="Base site"
jcr:description=""
allowedPaths="[/content]"
ranking="{Long}100">
<jcr:content
    cq:designPath="/etc/designs/basesite"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
    cq:allowedTemplates="[/apps/powerade/templates/homepage]"
    sling:resourceType="foundation/components/redirect"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Homepage - can create any page(except basepage) **but only homepage can create contentpage**

homepage template .context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
jcr:title="Homepage"
jcr:description="Homepage"
ranking="{Long}100">
<jcr:content
    jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
    cq:allowedTemplates="[/apps/powerade/templates/.*]"
    sling:resourceType="powerade/pages/homepage"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Contentpage - **it can be created only on the homepage or contentpage, and contentpage can create only contentpages**

contentpage template .context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
jcr:title="Contentpage"
jcr:description="Contentpage"
ranking="{Long}99"
allowedParents="[/apps/powerade/templates/homepage, /apps/powerade/templates/contentpage]"
allowedChildren="[/apps/powerade/templates/contentpage]">
<jcr:content
    jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
    cq:allowedTemplates="[/apps/powerade/templates/.*]"
    sling:resourceType="powerade/pages/contentpage"/>
</jcr:root>
```

I'm trying to implement these requirements with the aid of the parameters allowedParents and allowedChildren, but unfortunately it does not work

Contentpage not see the template contentpage (can't create Contentpage2):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/quHN4.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a working version! But we must be careful not to put the space

```
allowedParents="[/apps/powerade/templates/homepage, /apps/powerade/templates/contentpage]" (don't work)

allowedParents="[/apps/powerade/templates/homepage,/apps/powerade/templates/contentpage]" (works!)
```